# rsync failed: Permission denied (13) cygwin

Tags: rsync, cygwin

I have mounted my destination server on my windows machine on `Y:` drive. I created a folder on the destination folder and when I open cygwin and run my rsync command to move data from my machine to the mounted server I get this error `rsync failed: Permission denied (13)` and I find that destination folder which I created which had permissions set as it's parent's folder now changed permissions to the local machine. Not sure why? I want to use rsync to move the data from my machine to the mounted server and match the permissions of the destination's parent folder. If I use the same command from my other machine which runs ubuntu it works fine. Any advice?

This is how my rsync command looks like:

```
rsync -0 --files-from=- -ptOW --info=progress2 --no-super --remove-source-files - /cygdrive/y/parent_folder/folder_to_be_copied
```

Comment: You could try WSL (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) for an almost full Linux experience on Windows. This solved Cygwin issues for me.